# Commute between California City and LA by general aviation plane?

Tags: air-travel, commute

Last time I visited Cali City, I found out there is actually an airport there. That got me thinking...
Is it practical to commute between Cali City and LA by general aviation by plane?
It sounds a crazy idea, but I know that there are people in Alaska doing just that.

Let's say that I have a PPL license, a fairly reliable plane let's say a Cirrus SR22, commuting between L71(California City Municipal Airport) to KEMT(San Gabriel Valley Airport), the trip is just around 100nm. What would be the cost of fuel, airport fee and maintenance for one trip? What will be some problem with doing this?

From what I can see you got to navigate around the restrict airspace at Mojave and Edward, wether in the area is fairly good but I feel it does get some nasty wind once a while. I am not a pilot yet, just my judgment from a few lessons.

Comment: I'm not sure this is off-topic here (commuting questions are on-topic), but you're probably going to get better answers at [aviation.stackexchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) if it's on-topic over there, especially about things like fuel and maintenance.

Comment: What do you mean by "commute"?  Move there and use the plane to come in a few times a week, or do it once as a fun thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a "practical, answerable question based on actual problems" faced by the OP. See the Travel Help file for more: travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Questions about flying your own plane are on topic at our sister site [aviation.se].